# Storing integers from a text file into an integer array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a problem with an exercise, the statement is the following:

- save a matrix with a name `matriu[7][10]`, Getting the numbers from a file.

Here the text of the file: `matrix.txt`

```
1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,
```

Following is the version I did, but it fails. Can someone help me fix?

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    char linea[3024];
    int j;
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("matriu.txt", "r");
    int matriu[7][10];

    while (fgets(linea, sizeof(linea), file) != NULL) {

        char* token;

        token = strtok(linea, ",");

        printf("%s\n", token);

        while (token != NULL) {

            token = strtok(NULL, ",");

            if (token != NULL)

                matriu[i][j] = atoi(token);

            printf("%s\n", token);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            printf("%d\n", matriu[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code, not an image

Comment: I wonder where does this idea come from that _posting screenshots_ of code would be ok? Well it is **not**. What makes it difficult copy/pasting your code into the question and formatting it as code? It's two clicks away. Do you expect people admire your screenshots or help you?

Comment: Okey, sorry. I put the code right now

Comment: Also, you have this tagged as both `c` and `c#`. The code you have provided is `c`. Please remove the `c#` tag.

Comment: Apart from the error in not checking the result of `fopen` your use of `strtok` is all wrong (for one thing you throw away the first result). It should be more like this: `token = strtok(linea, " ,"); while(token != NULL) { /* process_the_token; */ token = strtok(NULL, " ,"); }`. Note that I added a `space` to the delimiters - this would not matter if you use `sscanf` but you are using `atoi`.

Comment: `i` and `j` are not initialized in the first loop.

Comment: Mybad: `atoi` tolerates leading whitespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've saved the matrix by reading one character at a time.

- if the scanned character is either `'0'` or `'1'` , then I save it into the `matriu[7][10]` matrix/array.
- else I scan next character.

here is the code I used to PERFORM the above actions :

```
for(i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        do
        {
            // i've declared a character ch to read each character
            ch=getc(file);
        }while(ch!='0' && ch!='1'); 
        matriu[i][j]=(ch-'0');//converting char to integer
    }
}
```

I hope you understand the above code, so all together your code would be :

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int i,j,matriu[7][10];
    char ch; //the character 
    FILE * file;
    file=fopen("matriu.txt", "r");

    for(i=0;i<7;i++) //the mechanism
    {
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            do
            {
                ch=getc(file);
            }while(ch!='0' && ch!='1');
            matriu[i][j]=(ch-'0');
        }
    }

    for (i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<10; j++)
        {
            printf("%d\n", matriu[i][j]);

        }
    }
    fclose(file); //you forgot this in your code
    return 0;
 }
```

It worked as desired, and lastly

> **NOTE**: you forgot to close the file pointer in you code

Comment: Thanks you for your answer and your time.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LINE 7
#define ROW 10

int main()
{
    int i = 0, j = 0, matriu[LINE][ROW];
    char letter = ' ';
    FILE* file = fopen("matriu.txt", "r");
    if(!(file))
    {
        printf("file open ERROR!\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while(i < LINE * ROW)
    {
        letter = fgetc(file);
        if(letter != ' ' && letter != ',')
        {
            *(matriu + i) = letter - 30;//because it returns the ascii code
            i++;
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < LINE;i++)
    {
        for(j = 0;j < ROW;j++)
        {
            printf("%d",matriu[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Deliberately overflowing an array and taking advantage of *undefined behaviour* by exceeding its bounds? Better would be to keep track of `j` too and reset `i` at the end of each row.

Comment: This code, have an error in: *(matriu+i) = letter - 30;

Comment: `*(matriu + i) = letter - 30;` --> `*((int*)matriu + i) = letter - '0';`

Comment: @WeatherVane or instead `letter-48`, since 48 is ascii value of zero

Comment: @CherubimAnand no, please don't use magic numbers. Apart from not necessarily having the ASCII char set, it makes the code more readable to use `'0'`. The answer used `30` which was presumably intended to be `0x30`.

Comment: Fine @WeatherVane I'll surely avoid using ASCII values